# HTML5 - Suggestions for where to start from

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs

I want to look into developing mobile applications using HTML5. I'm very new to it and do not have any idea about HTML5. I would like to take some suggestions about where to get the basic tutorials for starters and what is the best IDE to use.

Comment: I wonder why you tagged this question a `sencha-touch` and `sencha` If you are still learning the basics.

Comment: It seemed to be related to HTML5.. Is it wrong to do so

Comment: any way can u suggest me an IDE for HTML5

Comment: sencha-touch is more related to Javascript Oriented Development. For your jquerymobile would be a good way to go.

Comment: @vivek, use anyother editor with which you do HTML no need for different IDE.

Comment: Well just to make sure i have not mis-interpreted about HTML5, is it used for cross platform mobile app building???

Comment: @Uday, just thought an IDE with suggestion dialog and color notions will help me. That's the reason i was looking out for an IDE. and more over i'm really new to the concept of HTML as a whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still learning the basics HTML5 then [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) is a very good reference. It tell you about all the semantic meaning of tags and the correct use of it.

Next, look into a quick start tutorial from [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-basic-html5-template/) which will get you started.

Comment: Can u clarify this to me. HTML5 is used to build cross platform mobile applications right???

Comment: HTML5 is not used to for mobile application. It is the the latest Specification of HTML, using which you build web application. How you will use this to make a cross platform mobile application is a different thing.

Comment: On k I'm seeking help to create a cross platform mobile application and this is what i got as suggestion to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to HTML5 then I would recommend [**Headfirst HTML5**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449390544), its a very comprehensive book with each of the JavaScript APIs(geolocation, audio, video, webworkers, canvas etc.) explained very well.

If you want to go with simple overview of the language there is introductory video on HTML5 by Google's Open Web Advocacy, http://youtu.be/siOHh0uzcuY . Its dated, though you can get the feel of HTML5.

**&** Not to forget Divya Manian's awesome work on [**HTML5Please**](http://html5please.com/)

**EDIT:** for IDE I would recommend [SublimeText2](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-beta) which is very light weight.

You can also see Big IDE's like Microsoft Expression Web, Dreamweaver or Komodo Edit, Aptana Studio

**UPDATE:**  **Sencha Touch** is lightweight which doesn't depend on jQuery like its sister project(jQTouch). Sencha Touch is a framework and provides a number of functionalities the former could not develop(that is, API).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Out of curiosity what is sencha all about

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/ also..

Answer (score 0):

A very good way to start would be to learn basic HTML first(if you do not know that already), then HTML5. A nice site to learn both of these would be [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp). There you can learn at least the basics of HTML5.